# Recuperar toda la información de una base de datos en Mysql ocupando php en Android studio

Tags: java, mysql, android-studio, base-de-datos, phpmyadmin

estoy manipulando una base de datos en mysql ocupando archivos php para la inserción y eliminación de datos
pero necesito crear un  **php script** que me recupere la información de todas las columnas
**Ejemplo**: Nombre, ID, password etc
y todos estos datos dejarlos en una lista de Strings(o una lista de la columna entera)
He manipulado las consultas con  **Postman** en mi archivo php **getRowdata.php** y ha funcionado
pero en  android studio tengo un error de conexión

**getRowdata.php**

```
<?php
 
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='GET') {

        require_once("db.php");


        $query = "SELECT * FROM permisos";
        $result = $mysql-> query ($query);


             while($row = $result->fetch_array()){
                 $flag[]=$row;
               
            }
            
        echo json_encode($flag);
        $result->close();
        
        }
    
?>
```

**android studio**

```
public void getRowdata(){


        String URL = "http://xxx.xxx.x.x/permisostemporales/getRowdata.php";

        JsonArrayRequest jsonArrayRequest=new JsonArrayRequest(URL, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                JSONObject jsonObject = null;
                for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                    try {
                        jsonObject = response.getJSONObject(2);
                        Toast.makeText(context, jsonObject.getString("nombre"), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        Toast.makeText(context, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }

            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Toast.makeText(context, "Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
        );

        requestQueue.add(jsonArrayRequest);

    }
```

La conexión funciona en Postman y en el navegador, estos me recupera los datos que necesito pero en  android entra a la función onErrorResponse
He intentado debugear la app pero no puedo encontrar el error en la consola
Soy muy nuevo en php y Mysql si pudieran ayudarme explicando simple lo agradecería muchísimo

Comment: oh es verdad, lo hare

Answer (score 0):

Prueba a incluir el bloque dentro de un try por ejemplo así:

```
public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
try {
                JSONObject jsonObject = null;
                for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                    try {
                        jsonObject = response.getJSONObject(2);
                        Toast.makeText(context, jsonObject.getString("nombre"), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        Toast.makeText(context, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
} catch (Exception e) { 
   e.printStackTrace(); // Esto te capturara cualquier error y lo mostrará 
}
            }
```

con Exception capturará cualquier tipo de error y lo sacará por los log's, el stack del error será largo pásalo y lo analizamos :)

saludos!

Comment: El error era la IP de la URL , no sabia que al reiniciar el pc se cambiaba, ahora con la función que mostré(getRowdata()) puedo recuperar toda la columna de nombres id etc. El problema ahora es que necesito pasar estos datos a otra clase y ya que no puedo retornar ahí use un Intent
Intent name = new Intent(context,Administracion.class);//Nombre de mi otra clase
name.putExtra("nombre",nombre);

Pero me da error en un valor nulo:

java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo

Creo que estoy haciendo algo al revés